# MindAR, Image tracking, no video is played or starts on its own

Tags: javascript

I use MindAR to create Image tracking, but my video plays itself on Android, and only the first frame is shown on iOS. On Android, after loading the web page, the music from the video starts playing immediately. And the video did not appear when you hovered over the trigger.

Below is my HTML code, I will be glad to help you solve the problem.

I tried A-Frame video not playing, only 1st frame visible - this is an article on StackOverflow. I didn't succeed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mind-ar@1.2.2/dist/mindar-image-aframe.prod.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene
      mindar-image="imageTargetSrc: ./image_tracking/targets.mind;"
      vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"
      device-orientation-permission-ui="enabled: false"
    >
      <a-camera position="0 0 0" look-controls="enabled: false"></a-camera>
      <a-entity mindar-image-target="targetIndex: 0">
        <a-video
          src="./image_tracking/video/video.mp4"
          position="0 0 0"
          height="1.33"
          width="1"
          rotation="0 0 0"
          id="vid"
          hide-on-play="#vid"
        ></a-video>
      </a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```